# Azure search index rebuild strategy using C#

Tags: c#, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search that indexes an Azure Storage every 5 minutes. Since the storage may also have deletes ocassionally I was looking for a way to handle those. From the documentation I understand that unless you manually delete an index or rebuild the index.

A full rebuild would do, but I would like to keep downtime to a minimum. I was looking for a strategy to do so. Right now I thought about building a second index that's build up and once it's done delete the old one; It however feels a bit clumsy as I would have to keep track of the index names.

Right now it looks like this (simplified):

```
//create new index
searchClient.Indexes.CreateOrUpdate(index);

//update indexer
var indexer = searchClient.Indexers.Get("testindexer");
indexer.TargetIndexName = index.Name;
searchClient.Indexers.CreateOrUpdate(indexer.Name);

//reset and run indexer
searchClient.Indexers.Reset(indexer.Name);
searchClient.Indexers.Run(indexer.Name);

//at this point the new index is used

//delete old index
searchClient.Indexes.Delete(oldIndex.Name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [documentation for recommended practices on reindexing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex) similar to the scenario that you mention that may be useful.  In addition, if you would like Azure Search to support a data deletion policy for hard deletions in the future, there is [an uservoice request that you can vote on here.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/33939013-adding-hard-delete-policy-to-all-of-indexer)  As the other answer mentions, the recommended policy for this today is using [the soft delete option that Azure Search provides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#incremental-indexing-and-deletion-detection), so if you can restructure how your deletes are done then that would be a potential option as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it looks like incremental indexing is enabled for you by default:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Additionally you can use "soft delete" option in case those deleted files might reappear at some point.

Comment: Incremental indexing seems to only apply to new files. The `soft delete` option won't work in this context as the file is instantly deleted and not available for reprocessing. I do wonder though why the documentation asks for setting up a seperate property for it. There's already a build-in status property (when checking the properties of a soft-deleted file from the Azure Portal) that I can't seem to use for the `soft delete` option at the index.